# Vehicle wiring diagram - interpreting symbols compared to actual physical devices

Tags: circuit-analysis, wiring, automotive, diagram

I am going thru my bike's schematic/wiring diagram and going wire by wire I think I'm starting to understand how it works from turning the key onward. But some things are still confusing so perhaps some of you may help me out. In the picture I have three qualms, three things I'm confused about.

1. Diagram vs. actual switch on the bike - the "Passing" button seems to be wired in straight to the "Hi" wire, so you can activate it temporarily (push the Passing button, turn on high beam, release the button - turn off). Would this imply that there's no separate wire for this function, just internal "bridge" short connection between Passing contact and high beam wire?
2. Diagram vs. actual slide switch - there are three positions I can choose here, white dot is "all lights off", middle symbol is "position light" and left symbol is headlights on. However, the way I see it on the diagram, with two switches connected by the vertical line, it seems that the off position is missing? Looking at the diagram, where would the middle position be? Also I can't find what HL and TL means, perhaps Head Light and Tail Light, although that doesn't make much sense to me.
3. Fuel cut and engine stop relay - from the diagram it looks like 4 pole relay, and in each symbol, I would say top two wires are switches, and bottom two wires are coil that pulls the switch on or off. However, if you look at the wires coming into the relay, it seems that two wires in the middle go both to switch pole and coil pole?

Any help welcome and appreciated :D

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Would this imply that there's no separate wire for this function

Yes.

> However, the way I see it on the diagram, with two switches connected by the vertical line, it seems that the off position is missing? Looking at the diagram, where would the middle position be?

For some of these schematic symbols, you're just supposed to know.  You know that you start with all off, then turn on the marker lights, then turn on the headlights.  So from that actual function, you deduce that one switch closes and then the other, no matter what the diagram implies or fails to imply.

> Also I can't find what HL and TL means, perhaps Head Light and Tail Light.

Probably exactly that.  Again, "just supposed to know".  Assume the diagram isn't fully clear (and possibly not fully accurate), and think it through.

> However, if you look at the wires coming into the relay, it seems that two wires in the middle go both to switch pole and coil pole?

Clearly yes.  You can always get a meter and check.  The common wires are probably either ground, with power being applied elsewhere, or power, with ground being applied elsewhere.

For instance, in the fuel cut relay, if the common wire is power, then whenever the other end of the coil wire is grounded (with a switch, I assume), then the relay will close and supply power to -- whatever it powers (a fuel solenoid?), which presumably is grounded on its other end.  OTOH, if that common wire is ground, then applying +battery to the coil will *ground* the wire coming out of the relay contacts, which would power up something whose other end is connected to +battery.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, so the wiring diagram isn't 100% as-is replica of the circuit, more like 90-something % with some common sense / experience needed to be applied. I have traced all the wires of the relay in question, Fuel Cut Relay. Top wire, labeled Br goes only to one fuel pump pole. Bl/W wires go to injectors and ECU and Br/Bl also goes to ECU, so that relay doesn't touch the fuse box at all, so I'm wondering how do I get it powered when I press the start button :D